# How to send live messages from one form to another in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is to send messages from one form to another, **as I type in the textbox of form1 is should get reflected in the textbox of form2**. It is like a live tutorial or live chat in windows forms in C#. Similar to server client program, one form is server and other is client,keep sending message from server to client as I **type** or **keypress**.

Form1 Function Code(Server)

code of the textbox on keypress function
on keypress sends the value to client form

```
    private void msg_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

            int n = e.KeyChar;
            String s = n.ToString();
            msg_box1.AppendText(n.ToString());
            byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

            nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, s.Length);
   }
```

In the above code msg is the textbox(multiline). I have used a keypress function to generate and send the ascii value of the keypressed to the client form.

Form2 Function Code (Client)

```
 var listenthread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] instream = new byte[100];
                    ns.Read(instream, 0, 100);
                    string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream);

                    int v = Int32.Parse(data);
                    char c = (char)v;
                    //MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
                    if (v == (int)Keys.Back)
                    {
                        //SendKeys.send("{BKSP}");
                        ;
                    }
                    else if (v == (int)Keys.Delete)
                    {
                        //SendKeys.send("{BKSP}");
                        ;
                    }
                    else if (v == (int)Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        //SendKeys.send("{BKSP}");
                        ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Action update = () => msg_box1.AppendText(c.ToString());
                        msg_box1.Invoke(update);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        });

        listenthread.IsBackground = true;
        listenthread.Start();
```

The above is the code for the client to receive message from server continuously so a background process is made to run.

On execution, the two forms run without errors, and able to send char on keypress from form1 to form2 but

**the backspace key, enter key, delete key are not getting reflected to form2's textbox when i use it in form1's textbox.** And moreover **the cursor itself** is not visible in textbox of form2 when I start to type in textbox of form1.

I have even tried using sendkeys.send() method, but it executes in form1 rather in form2.

My questions aim is to make a live e-learning based form, a**s we keep typing in form1 it should appear in form2**, with all backspace, enter key working on **keypress rather programmatically** invoking it.

Comment: Are you willing to make IP Based connection?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make IP Based connection. Connection code is working properly, only the live msg sending is problem. you want me to upload entire code? Vijay Kumbhoje

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to make this possible, but none of it is "automatic" as you are expecting. You seem to be suggesting that the 2 windows forms will work similar to a client - server system, but that also implies that the 2 forms will be hosted in separate processes? Is that accurate?

Your comments seem to suggest that, you are trying it as a IP client/server and having problems with propagating text changes done on server to the client. With your key-based solution, you will run into problems when you have special characters like backspace. You will have to implement special key handling on the client side to make it work.

I would suggest that you not send a message to the client on a "KeyTyped" Event and rather let the user press some "send button" or return key to send the message to the client. This way you will eliminate the special handling from the client side and the controls on the server side will handle teh special keys appropriately